# Scala regex confusion between \b and \s

Tags: regex, scala

I have a regex that works with \b but not with \s - which confuses me as I thought that \s is a superset of \b

this code works:

```
   val innerString = """Product\b"""
   val r = s"(?m)^.*$innerString(.*)$$".r
   logger.info(s"$r")
   val text = """Product Name NOCOPAR Oil Series"""
   logger.info(s"$text")
   val stuff = r.findAllIn(text).toSeq
   if (stuff.size > 0)
    logger.info(s"${stuff}")
   if (stuff.size > 0) {
       val productName = stuff.head.replaceAll(innerString, "").trim
        logger.info(s"$productName")
   }
```

Generates this output:

> INFO 2017-08-02 16:43:17.405 [main] c.s.d.t.SingleDocRegExExplore 23 - (m?)^.*Product\b(.*)$
>
> INFO 2017-08-02 16:43:17.411 [main] c.s.d.t.SingleDocRegExExplore 25 - Product Name NOCOPAR Oil Series
>
> INFO 2017-08-02 16:43:17.416 [main] c.s.d.t.SingleDocRegExExplore 28 - Stream(Product Name NOCOPAR Oil Series)
>
> INFO 2017-08-02 16:43:17.417 [main] c.s.d.t.SingleDocRegExExplore 31 -  Name NOCOPAR Oil Series

but when I switch to \s

```
    val innerString = """Product\s"""
val r = s"(?m)^.*$innerString(.*)$$".r
logger.info(s"$r")
val text = """Product Name NOCOPAR Oil Series"""
logger.info(s"$text")
val stuff = r.findAllIn(text).toSeq
if (stuff.size > 0)
    logger.info(s"${stuff}")
if (stuff.size > 0) {
    val productName = stuff.head.replaceAll(innerString, "").trim
    logger.info(s"$productName")
}
```

I get

> INFO 2017-08-02 16:50:30.287 [main] c.s.d.t.SingleDocRegExExplore 23 - (m?)^.*Product\s(.*)$
>
> INFO 2017-08-02 16:50:30.291 [main] c.s.d.t.SingleDocRegExExplore 25 - Product Name NOCOPAR Oil Series

Is this making any sense?

Scala is 2.11.8, java is 1.8.131

Comment: Why use `(m?)` (an optional `m` char) before the start of the string? Also, `\s` is a consuming pattern matching a whitespace, while `\b` is a non-consuming, zero-width assertion, matching a location between a non-word and a word char, or start/end of string and a word char.

Comment: the (m?) was an inversion - I've corrected it to (?m) for multilne support.

Comment: So I think I understand why the \b works - it detects an end of word (ie non letter).  But still don't understand why the \s doesn't.

Comment: Read my first comment. You are wrong about `\b`. And about `\s`.